# MySQL works in terminal on PHPmyadmin but does not work in php script?

Tags: php, mysql

Title pretty much explains it here is what I have tried this is my little test script to check if the mysql query works

```
$servername = "HIDDEN";
$username = "HIDDEN";
$password = "HIDDEN";
$dbname = "fbaFees";
/////////////////////////////////////

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected to database successfully<br><br>";

$sqlcheck = "SELECT * FROM fbafee_table WHERE ASIN = 'B07GC6DXFQ' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;"; 

if ($conn->query($sqlcheck) === TRUE) {

    echo "New record created successfully<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sqlcheck . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

This script gives me this error:

```
Error: SELECT * FROM fbafee_table WHERE ASIN = 'B07GC6DXFQ' ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

This is the mysql query that works on phpmyadmin

```
Error: SELECT * FROM fbafee_table WHERE ASIN = 'B07GC6DXFQ' ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

edit:
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and add the full text of the error you are getting.

Comment: What is the Error Message?

Comment: Thats actually part of the issue thats all it shows! Just edited to show the image

Comment: Is there a loop and 2 different statements?

Comment: Nah there is just a loop of that statment I only open the connection once and then run the query over and over but the answer below seems to have fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the code with the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM fbafee_table WHERE ASIN = 'B07GC6DXFQ' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;"; 
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result && $result->num_rows>0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         // do stuff with your row data
         echo $row['COLUMN_NAME'];   
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>" . $query;
}
```

The `SELECT` query selects data from the database, so if you check if the result is strictly equal to `TRUE`, the result is not. You need to cycle the results. If there's no rows returned, then you display the error using `mysqli_error($conn)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the $conn->query method will return a result set when it finds are record not the boolean TRUE. It returns the boolean false if there is no result found. So you have to slightly change your code first to check for unavailability and then the availability as follows

```
if (!$conn->query($sqlcheck)) {

   echo "Error: " . $sqlcheck . "<br>" . $conn->error;

} else {

   echo "New record created successfully<br>";
}
```